# How to open .ps1 file in PowerShell ISE in c#

Tags: c#, wpf, powershell-ise

I have a file explorer project, it could display all of the files in treeview, some files are .ps1 files, when user click it, I want to use PowerShell ISE to open it. When I use

```
Process.Start(filePath)
```

it always opened with Notepad. Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have an example of poweshell execution without opening window. just replace the -File path and assign or remove parameters when needed:

```
Process.Start("powershell"," -NoLogo -NonInteractive -File C:\Scripts\YouScript.ps1 -Param1 TestBackup");
```

Simplest example:

```
Process.Start("powershell.exe","C:\Scripts\MyScript.ps1");
```

Another one using string formt and single quotes for arguments:

```
Process.Start("Powershell.exe", @"""ScriptwithArguments.ps1"" 'arg1' 'arg2 asdf'");
```

Comment: Hi @Carlos, thanks for your quick reply! I want the file opened in Powershell ISE editor. For example, there're 2 .ps1 files, when I click the first one, open a tab in the ISE and display the file content, click the second one, open a new tab to display the file content.

Comment: Change "Powershell.exe" as "Powershell_ise.exe", then it works!

Comment: Yeah. Dont remember the exactly exe name